# I am taking image as byte of array type. How can I do accept only specific range of image size?

Tags: java

In method I am taking bytes of array of image as parameter and I want to before processing this image must be satisfy some condition regarding size or dimension.

```
private boolean isAcceptable(byte [] doc){
       //code or logic for accept 100Kb to 4Mb 
       return null;
    }
```

Comment: What about a if statement ?

Answer (score 4):

if you want to check size of the data you get, you need to count bytes in your array:

```
private boolean isAcceptable(byte [] doc){
    //code or logic for accept 100Kb to 4Mb 
    return doc.length >= 100 * 1024 && doc.length <= 4 * 1024 * 1024;
}
```

Comment: this mean 1Kb equals to 1 length value?

Comment: no, length = 1 => your data contains 1Byte, length = 1024 => data contains 1KB

Comment: can you add some verified source to justify this

Comment: well, you have an array of bytes, the number of bytes in the array is length, so if you have 1024 bytes in the array, you automatically have 1 KB of data in it